# Automate printing Mathcad sheets to PDF

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, cygwin, vbscript, mathcad

I am trying to print all files in certain format (i.e. `*.xmcd`) in a folder to PDF. I already made AdobePDF my default printer. I want to do this task using powershell but when I run it it throws an error, which I think has to do something with Mathcad.

I also added `VBScript` tag as I am thinking about using visual basic for this purpose.

This is the **command**:

```
Start-Process -FilePath “internal.company.com\path\to\the\file.xmcd” –Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} | kill
```

And the **error** that I get:

[image]

It basically should get the file, start printing and after 10 seconds close the application.

I also tried cygwin and `cygstart` like below but it gives me an error;

```
cygstart --print myfile.xmcd
```

and the error is: `Unable to start 's.xmcd': The DDE transaction failed.`

Need to figure out a way to print mathcad sheets using powershell or batch/bash script.

**Note**: Mathcad sheets have XML format.

**Note-2:** `Out-Print` gives a pdf of the xml.

**Note-3:** `cmd.exe /C ASSOC .xmcd` gives me `.xmcd=Mathcad`.

And, `cmd.exe /c ftype Mathcad` gives me `Mathcad="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mathcad\Mathcad 15\mathcad.exe" /dde`.

Comment: What is the output of the command `& cmd.exe /C ASSOC .xmcd`? Have you investigated `Out-Printer`?

Comment: @lit `Out-Printer` prints the XML format of the file. I think I need to somehow open the file with Mathcad.exe and then print it.

Comment: @lit I added output of `cmd.exe /C ASSOC .xmcd` in the question.

Comment: What is the output of `& cmd.exe /c ftype Mathcad`?

Comment: @lit `Mathcad="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mathcad\Mathcad 15\mathcad.exe" /dde`

Comment: Does the simple example in the Start-Process help work? `Start-Process -FilePath "myfile.txt" -WorkingDirectory "C:\PS-Test" -Verb Print`

Comment: It does work. but not for the `.xmcd` file of course. For a text file it does its job with no error.

Comment: Please try quoting the -Verb. `-Verb "Print"`

Comment: @lit It does give me the same error. It opens mathcad but the sheet won't load. and no print out.

Comment: Please try specifying the -FilePath with `"\\internal.company.com\path\to..."` or with `"\\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME\path\to..."` or with `"D:\path\to..."`.

Comment: @lit already tried that with different path and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this;

```
for %f in (*.xmcd) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mathcad\Mathcad 15\mathcad.exe" -p %f
```

It will prompt the save dialog and you need to hit <kbd>OK</kbd> to save it as PDF (or send it to your default printer).

It is wise to not run so many files (10~20 would be good) at the same time as it may causes some errors including licensing but not limited to that.

Comment: Glad you found a way. I am not sure why you would want to wait. Does every "print" b mathcad.exe cause a dialog box to appear, or is that from the Adobe PDF printer driver?

Comment: @lit it's from Adob PDF.

Comment: This may be relevant. http://khkonsulting.com/2013/01/prevent-the-save-dialog-when-printing-to-the-adobe-pdf-printer/

Comment: @lit Indeed it is. But unfortunately we don't have admin access to registry on company's machines. But anyhow, I now know it is possible. Thank you for your help.